# Variable that changes from String to Integer after some IF ELSE tests

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem and i cant find a solution.
After a html post i have a variable that correctly assigned as the user select "M" or "F".
Im sorry if the source is bad written, it's my first time coding!!

**HTML:**

```
<select style="width:75px;" name="sesso" multiple>
    <option value="m">Male</option>
    <option value="f">Female</option>
</select>
```

Here is a part of the PHP code where I find the problem:

```
$reg_nome = strip_tags($_POST['nome']);
$reg_username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$reg_password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$reg_passwordck = strip_tags($_POST['passwordck']);
$reg_sesso = strip_tags($_POST['sesso']);
$reg_data = date("Y-m-d");
$uomo = "m";
$donna = "f";
```

Here it works. The printed variable `$reg_sesso` is correct "M" or "F".

```
echo "sesso = $reg_sesso";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $reg_username);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($query_username);
$stmt->store_result();
$n_row = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();
if ($n_row==1)  //check if the user exists
{                 
    echo "L'utente $reg_username è già registrato";
}
else {
        if (preg_match("#.*^(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$#", $reg_password)) //check if password is ok
        {

        if($reg_password==$reg_passwordck) //check if two pass are the same
        {

        if($reg_sesso=$uomo||$reg_sesso=$donna) //se è stato inserito M o F
        {
            echo " sesso= $reg_sesso ";

            // Here $reg_sesso is 1 not "M" or "F"

            $password_sha1=(sha1($reg_password));
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (nome,username,password,data,sesso) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $reg_nome, $reg_username, $password_sha1, $reg_data, $reg_sesso);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            movePage(301,"login.php");
            exit;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning, not comparing. Use `==` to compare values.

Comment: You're right that was the problem... i feel so stupid :( THANKS